# Can I SUM a certain cell value using a query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Lets assume I have a table with two columns: key and value.

can I return the SUM of all the values that answer the WHERE key = something condition?

For example:

```
1 30
2 50
1 40
```

Can I return `70` using a query resembles to this

```
SELECT SUM(value) WHERE key = 1
```

Comment: Yes. Let's assume you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good attempt. You were pretty close. **[Read Aggregate Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)**

And you can use the below Query to get the Output.

```
select sum(values)
from table_name
where key='1'
group by key
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can, just try to do it

check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum